Outdoor installation advice for 6 ga ground THHN wire in liquid tight flexible non-metallic conduit (LFNC)?
I'm running a 6 ga stranded copper THHN ground wire about 70 feet total outdoors in dedicated 1/2" LFNC to retrofit equipment ground (EGC) to old ungrounded outlets in the back side of my house.
I've got easy access to tap onto the auxiliary grounding electrode conductor (GEC) at the more distant ground electrode outside the garage near the panel, so my plan is to tap the end of the 6 ga THHN onto the aux GEC bare wire with a split bolt in a weatherproof junction box mounted to the aluminum siding about a foot above  ground level.
The 6 ga THHN would then run in 1/2" LFNC a total of about 70 feet along the exterior siding, mostly just under the roof eave, passing through an exterior intermediate junction box after the first 25 feet of run and ending in another exterior junction box. Three 90 degree bends in that first segment, then one 90 degree bend in the 2nd 40 foot run after the intermediate box. First run segment has 8 feet vertical, all the rest is horizontal. Two of the bends are building corners, so smaller radius preferred.
The junction boxes are cast aluminum weathertight boxes, and the 6 ga will be bonded to each via lay-in lugs.
I have not used LFNC before, so have some questions:

Is 1/2" LFNC sufficient for this one 6 ga THHN ground wire? Any pulling issues to worry about, e.g. radius of the bends? Pulling lube needed?

I could use cast aluminum LBs (conduit bodies) at the two building corners instead of bending the LFNC, but wouldn't I have to somehow bond them to the EGC? No pre-made lay-in lug mount connection in the LBs, so drilling and tapping for a #10-32 screw to secure a lug? Do LBs need to be attached to the siding directly, or is their connection to LFNC sufficient to secure/support?

LFNC will be mounted to siding via Arlington snap-in plastic offset conduit clamps (allowing some sideways motion), while junction boxes will be screwed to the aluminum siding. Do I need to worry about expansion issues? (annual temps in northern Calif range from 30-ish to 100 F)


Thanks for any advice on this!

LFNC is an odd choice for this. It's also by far the most evil conduit type to pull in, in my experience. Consider EMT instead...

What's the reasoning for the LFNC?  You should be able to run 6AWG bare without physical damage protection (see 250.120(C))

I suppose it's aesthetics, weight, and not having uninformed people (kids, gardeners, etc) accidentally cut/pull a bare wire. Plenty of human activity on the patio next to these walls. I'm not sure how much weight the 60? year old aluminum siding can hold, so I'm avoiding steel conduit. I'm now leaning toward using aluminum LBs at the two building corners rather than bending the LFNC there; that gives me pulling access, too. Basically wanting to do it once and not have to think about it again, so obsessing beforehand.

Also, thinking that using rigid PVC conduit would involve expansion joint(s) over those lengths and not wanting to deal with that.

No, you don't need to bond conduit bodies you are merely passing through.  Only if a splice happens there (which is generally a bad idea because conduit bodies lack the necessary cubic inches for a splice).
